# How to open a form from a button click from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one form "MainForm" and another form "LoginForm". There is a button in LoginForm which, when clicked, should display the MainForm.

I tried the following code, but I am getting an error saying
"The type or namespace name 'MainForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemly reference?)"

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm frm = new MainForm();
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Please help me out with this one.

Comment: Look at the code of MainForm and search the line _namespace_ Copy the text following the word namespace at the beginning of your login form code adding the word _using text_following_the_namespace_of_MainForm_;

Comment: Can you upload your solution, please?